# Created A Conditional Formula But unable to add further Conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I hope to get Some help. I am Stuck on a condition. Let me explain it.

**1.** There is `Col"L"` in sheet which is `AGE` and all conditions (Formulas) are lies on the `AGE`. Whenever any data is pasted in the the Sheet Including `AGE` then `Col"P"` is highlights in `Pink Color` (Pink means "Pending") and Column "AP" creates a NOTE like this `HEDAL - COM?  TH - 12-03-2021`.

**2.** If i mention the Date in `Col"P"` in Pink color then it gets `Green` and NOTE becomes like this `HEDAL - 2021 COMPLETE - TH - 12-03-2021`

**3.** I want If i mention "J" in highlighted cell of `Col"P"` then it should create Same NOTE as Pink Color has. That means if Cell is Pink or has "P" then it NOTE should be this `HEDAL - COM?  TO - 12-03-2021`

If it has Date it would be like this HEDAL - 2021 COMPLETE - TH - 12-03-2021`

If it has nothing then it should be empty.

It is must to have Col"C" and Col"I" in the NOTE formula.

Your help will be appreciated.

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0UFnnfd87ZrqZbLyBwSvOOI3Epd-YFJhiOSKPD_q0E/edit#gid=452585968)

```
=IF(AND($L3>=50,$L3<76,$P3="")," HEDAL - "&
IF(AND($L3>=50,$L3<76,$P3=""),"COM? ",IF($P3="J","COM? ",""))
&" "&$C3&" - "&TEXT($I3,"MM-DD-YYYY ")," HEDAL - "&TEXT(I3,"YYYY")&" COMPLETE - "&$C3&" - "&TEXT($I3,"MM-DD-YYYY"))
```

Comment: Can we use a custom formula via apps script for easier identification of the cells to be emptied?

Comment: Actually No, I am stuck on this single condition, There are multiple column Like `Column "P"` in Original sheets. So script will be enough long when i moved to other columns. I need this using Same formula. So i can modify it when changes will be required.

Comment: I meant was using a custom formula to help your existing formula there. Basically a custom formula is to be made to make the identification easier. I'm in no way removing your formula, it would be just enhanced with a custom formula. Would that be fine?

Comment: Yes it would be fine.

Comment: hi @HSHO, I have some clarification, please join me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239952/room-for-nazia-and-hsho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue in modifying the formula is when to leave it blank. Thus I used script to identify the color of the cell:

#### [Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788432/google-sheets-script-function-that-outputs-the-background-color-of-a-cell):

```
function GETBACKGROUNDCOLOR(cell){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getBackground();
}
```

#### Formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND($L3>=50,$L3<76,$P3=""),$P3="J")," HEDAL - COM? "&" "&$C3&" - "&TEXT($I3,"MM-DD-YYYY "),
IF(GETBACKGROUNDCOLOR(cell("address", $P3)) = "#ffffff", "", " HEDAL - "&TEXT(I3,"YYYY")&" COMPLETE - "&$C3&" - "&TEXT($I3,"MM-DD-YYYY")))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Combined the conditions in the first if statement since the first 2 can be combined (they have the same conditions) and have added an `OR` to combine it again with the `J` value in column `P`.
- `GETBACKGROUNDCOLOR` is used to check if a certain cell has white color (e.g. `#ffffff`). If it is white, then return blank. If it is not white and does not satisfy the earlier conditions, then proceed with "COMPLETE"

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware that my formula can be shorten using GAS. Thank you very much

Comment: It was the easiest approach I thought as sheets cannot determine if a cell has a background color or not, but apps script can, so you can combine it using custom formula and use it to identify the cells @HSHO

Comment: Yes it was great idea! Thank alot